# I want to connect the postgreSQL database from cPanel to my Next js 13 project using prisma orm

Tags: next.js, cpanel, prisma

I'm attempting to connect a PostgreSQL database hosted on cPanel to my Next.js 13 project using Prisma ORM. However, I'm encountering difficulty in determining the correct database URL. I've structured my DATABASE_URL as follows: DATABASE_URL="postgresql://user:password@host:5432/database-name"
But when I run npx prisma migrate dev --name name, it reports that it can't reach the database.

I've tried different variations, including the shared server IP address and the domain name, but none have worked for me.

Does anyone have insights or suggestions on how to resolve this issue? Your assistance is greatly appreciated.